# SCNAnimationPlayer to start playing animation on gesture

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, blender

I am using Scenekit/ ARKit for the code and Blender for my 3D models. I have a 3D model with some keyframe animations - created in Blender, which has been exported easily into XCode. Nothing complicated - it's just a cat moving a bit up and then down.

[image: Cat Animated]

I am using animation controls inside my tapGestureRecognizer. As soon as my view loads I have set the animation to be in paused state :-

```
nonGeometryObjectNode?.childNode(withName: "Armature", recursively: true)?.animationPlayer(forKey: "cat_animated-1")?.paused = true
```

Code for animation controls inside my tap gesture is as below.

```
let animationPlayer = hitResults.first?.node.parent?.childNode(withName: "Armature", recursively: true)?.animationPlayer(forKey: "cat_animated-1")
animationPlayer?.animation.autoreverses = true
animationPlayer?.animation.repeatCount = 1
animationPlayer?.animation.duration = 0.8
animationPlayer?.animation.blendInDuration = 0.2
animationPlayer?.animation.blendOutDuration = 0.2
animationPlayer?.paused = true
if (animationPlayer?.paused)! {
    animationPlayer?.play()
}
```

It works fine, the only problem is it works just one time when tap is performed for the very first time. I tried using `.paused`, `.stop()` inside my tapGesture code, but animationPlayer doesn't replay as it should every time I am tapping on it. There is no bool var in SCNAnimationPlayer or else which I can use to detect if the animation has played itself out, so that I can use `.stop()` and then `.play()` again.

I did see two instance vars animationDidStart and animationDidStop which I thought probably would be useful to manage what I need. But I am at loss of ways to use these. What would be really helpful is what should be used to play and stop/ pause my animation whenever I tap on the object. Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question but in case anyone stumbles across it in future, the default action is for the animation to be removed once complete.  Therefore to be able to play it again you need to set:

```
    animationPlayer?.animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```